# Will Azure allow you to send the file location of a "hosted" file as an url so that it can be downloaded when the Flask app has been deployed?

Tags: python, flask

Note: This is more of a research question, if I this is bad question and it sounds pretty stupid I applogize. While I believe in theory this should work I do not want to take any chances.

I have a python flask web application with an entire background script (which is too long to explain here) but in essence after a long "background" process it generates a ZIP file and sends the file location per mail using send GRID. In short terms the file location is being send as a clickable_url in a standard html template, which is used as the mail itself.

```
send_grid_mail = 'Classified
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))



def main(file_name: str,file_location:str, attachment_bool: bool, download_link:str, recipient_email: str):
    file_path = file_location
    if os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY') == None:
        print("No API KEY FOUND")
    else:
        
        print("API KEY FOUND")
    html_string = generate_html_content(attachment_bool,download_link)
    message = Mail(
            from_email='Classified',
            to_emails=recipient_email,
            subject='Uw data is gereed.',
            html_content= html_string)

    if attachment_bool is True:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.close()
        encoded_file = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
        attachment = Attachment()
        attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded_file)
        attachment.file_type = FileType('application/zip')
        attachment.file_name = FileName('{}.zip'.format(file_name))
        attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
        attachment.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID')
        message.attachment = attachment
    try:     
            response = sg.send(message)
            print(response.status_code)
            print(response.body)
            print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
            print("Failed scenario")
            print("Scenerio checking")


# Generates the HTML variables for the email page.
def generate_html_content(attachment_bool: bool,download_link: str):
    if attachment_bool is False:
        Letter_1 = "Helaas was deze te groot om via mail door te sturen."
        Letter_2 = "Klik hier om het bestand te downloaden."
    if attachment_bool is True:
        Letter_1 =  "U vindt het bestand terug in de bijlage."
        Letter_2 = "Is het bestand niet in de bijlage terug te vinden? Klik dan hier en download dan hier."
    return render_template(
        'email.html',
        message_1 = Letter_1,
        message_2 = Letter_2,
        link = download_link,
        title='YOU GOT MAIL'
         )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sending the mail and the link itself works...with the local file system I have set up, so I cannot really confirm there will be a download prompt.

For now this just works as local file location so, I cannot really test if it works by downloading the file.

For now where the file is stored is a local system variable called DATA_DIR but this also been programmed into Docker.
It is just "/data" to be simple.

Considering in the future when this application has been deployed to Azure it is of course stored inside a folder of the Web Application itself aka the "/data" folder.

But I am having doubts if this will work or not, when it is deployed to an azure virtual environment to host our web Application.

In theory this will work because the file, it is the same principal based on how you make webpage.

And you can refer to "local" files when you set up a website.
So I might be looking for that.
Now I am looking in to this Azure Blob Storage. so I am reading this up on as it goes on. It is just I am bit concered in this of security.

Comment: Will your file be stored inside the virtual machine on Azure or in the Azure Blob Storage? If it's in the virtual machine, you must use your Flask application to return it as in your localhost. If it's in a Blob Storage, you must configure it to allow public access or configure a gateway to ensure privacy and authentication.

Comment: I think its inside the virual machine considering there is a "/data" folder that will be created and used according to the docker-compose.

Return it as in your local host? You mean the fu,ction currently works at it is? Or do I still need something extra to do? Considering we have many files possibly where they will ne deleted after 10 days I do not think we need the Azure storage..but I am think I am considering adding this on the backlog. So does my function work as it is to return it as in your localhost? Because I cannot test it now as download prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to deserve files from the cloud:

- The first is from the hard drive attached to the virtual machine where your
  application is running. To deserve those files, there is absolutely
  no difference from deserving files from your computer or from any
  other personal computer. The inconvenient here, from the cloud point
  of view, is that your file can be deleted when stopping your virtual
  machine (depending on the strategies over the attached hard drive).
- The second option is to use Azure Blob Storage (AWS S3 if you're in AWS and Google Cloud Storage if you're in GCP). This managed service allows you to store files (or other blob objects) with high availability and a >99% SLA. Stopping and/or removing a virtual machine won't impact your stored data. The inconvenient here is that you must adapt your code to talk with this managed service instead of looking for file in your hard drive (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python).

Comment: Got one small question you said stopping the virtual machine? Does it technically not keep running to reach the webpage itself? Because I am pretty sure you have to set up the server and therefore the virtual machine itself keeps running till focurse the Azure Service stops it..Sorry if this sounds "nooby" first time I will integrate a python flask web application to Azure to deploy it.

Comment: The virtual machine can be stopped on demand to minimize costs. Or it can be shut down to some tehcnical problem of Azure. It works as a personal computer but available through the Azure console. Also, you will need to configure network accessto allow HTTP requests reach the VM

Comment: So that is how it is...Which makes it make it bit harder then. Conifgure network access is in the azure envoriment itself right? Hmm well guess I have to reconsider my planning. I might I think I know how to do it...kinda.
1: After the Zip file is create I will create a container for it.
2 I will send the file tot that container
3 I will request the file from the container and generate a download link for it
4 I will send that download link to my email send function like normal

Step 1&2 should be easy but step 3 & 4 that needs some research.

Comment: I'm not a professional on Azure, but I've been working many years on the Cloud (AWS and GCP) and the concepts are the same. I let you check which service fits best to your case. The on-boarding to the cloud computing is very easy. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/